# Uploading GPX Files to GPS (Garmin) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, garmin, gpsbabel

I am fairly new to QGIS and GIS in general so it's hard to tell what I'm doing wrong.

I am using a GPSMap 64st and can't seem to successfully upload any GPX files to it through QGIS.

I am able to select the correct data layers in the GPS Tool, can select my GPS device, and am using the USB port. Everything looks good and then I press 'OK' and the window closes but nothing happens. No error message, but when I check my GPS nothing is on it.

I have tried 'Edit Device' and adding in a new device as described here:
 [Quantum GIS – using a USB GPS device](https://nickmcw.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/quantum-gis-using-a-usb-gps-device/).

But it hasn't worked either. Also somewhere else I saw to change the commands provided in the link to use `gpsbabel` instead of `%babel` and that hasn't worked for me either. I also have separately downloaded the babel software just in case although I thought you should have that automatically installed with QGIS?

I'm using QGIS 3.4.14 although I tried in 3.10 too with no luck.

I am able to successfully download data from my GPS, although I usually just use the 'Load GPX File' in GPS tools and select the files directly from my Garmin in the file explorer window, I'm not sure if this is normally how you're supposed to do this.

I also have successfully uploaded the very same GPX files to my GPS using other programs (Ozi and DNRGPS) but I would like to be able to do this using QGIS.

Comment: `I am able to successfully download data from my GPS, although I usually just use the 'Load GPX File' in GPS tools and select the files directly from my Garmin in the file explorer window, I'm not sure if this is normally how you're supposed to do this.`
Just commenting on the download statement,  I have a GPSMap 64st too. I just download the GPX files, then add to my project using the QGIS Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer > File

I've never tried using GPS Babel

Comment: Not sure if it matters but what OS are you on?

Comment: I am running Windows 10

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked once when I set the specifications as explained by Jorma, but next time it didn´t work again.

Answer (score 2):

When exporting to gpx, choose Format = GPX, CRS = EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, don't use UTM, FORCE_GPX_TRACK = YES, these are essential. The CRS must be WGS84 and the EPSG for your area.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upload tracks to my old Garmin GPSMap64s and a Fenix 7x watch using QGIS 3.28. I couldn't do it by converting a layer to a GPX file. The way I did it was to save features of a vector polygon layer as a kml feature with geometry set to points. Then, I opened Garmin Basecamp and imported the kml file into Basecamp (the option to import is under the 'File' tab). Once the file is in Basecamp I rename the file, if I want to. Then, with the Garmin device connected and the internal storage of the device showing in Basecamp, I simply drag and drop the file into the internal storage of the device. An annoying feature of the GPSMap64s is that the tracks are not displayed on your device map by default. You have to go to your tracks in the device and manually select the 'show on map' option in your track manager, as well as change the color of the tracks (the default is grey). I noticed that the tracks drag and drop fairly quickly to the Fenix 7x watch but, you can't delete tracks through Basecamp from the watch. I had to connect the watch to my computer and access the watch files through File Explorer and delete them, which are saved as courses in the Courses Folder. For some reason, it deletes tracks very slowly through this method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GPX files are used as an intermediate exchange file type and not files that Garmin receivers would use/read directly. There is 3rd party software like [geopainting](https://www.geopainting.com/) that would allow you to author GPS maps.

However, that said, you can get away with using GPX files for just points.

While Garmin GPSs are useful and still have its place for outdoor navigation. Android apps like [Qfield](https://qfield.org/) works best with QGIS for highly customized field maps, data entry (offline supported) or just plain navigation.

Answer (score -1):

I don´t sure about your question, I´ll try to answer it. I mean you can upload your gpx file directly in QGIS (see the image attached). On the other hand, in older QGIS versions you could use other tools, here you have a post (sorry it is in Spanish): https://www.cursosgis.com/conversion-de-datos-gps-gpx-en-qgis/

Regards.[image: qgis]

Comment: The OP I think wants to upload from QGIS to the GPS device, (for example create a track to follow  then upload it) not download from the device to QGIS

Comment: Yes nmtoken is right I want to put gpx files onto my gps using QGIS